# Listing change history via webdav

Tags: svn, webdav

I'm trying to list the change history for a folder, similar to what the [Show Log](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) option in TortoiseSVN does. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible without going down the route of installing something like Trac.

To access my repository via web browser I go to a URL like the following

```
http://localhost/svn/ProjectDirectory
```

This lists everything in the working copy of this directory.

I have a hunch that what I'm trying to do is possible via the SVNSpecialURI but this appears to be completely undocumented.

An example of the usage of the above is this:

```
http://localhost/svn/ProjectDirectory/!svn/bc/10
```

This shows you revision 10.

I've seen hints in a few different places which mention `!svn/his`, namely an [unfinished official document](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-usage.html) and [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%22!svn/his%22&type=cs). I haven't been able to get these to work, getting the error

> "The requested URL /svn/ProjectDirectory/!svn/his was not found on
>   this server."

I've also had a glance at the source but my C++ isn't quite up to scratch. Any takers?

Comment: Anything useful in this link ? [svn-is-it-possible-to-get-the-list-of-revision-numbers-for-given-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633649/svn-is-it-possible-to-get-the-list-of-revision-numbers-for-given-path)

Comment: That looks like the result I want but through a different method. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to SVN right now but from what I gather the URL you tried is only internally accessible.

Using WebDAV means you need to use different HTTP verbs... WebDAV standard would use DeltaV (versioning) for such stuff... SVN seems to have implemented it a bit differently.

According to [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-protocol) you can see that the HTTP verb `REPORT` in combination with the project URL can be used to get history information...