# How to select all revision histories in SVN log using command line?

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

I can get the revision (log) details of SVN using command line. i have to write the revision number alone in a file, for this, `"/outfile:Sameple.txt"` command is used. This commands works for selected revisions in ShowLog dialog. So all details are not saved in Sample.txt file.

`Process proc = new Process(); proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"; proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:log /path:" + updateLocation + " /startrev:{2016-12-19} /endrev:{2016-11-11} /outfile:E:\\Sample.txt";`

Please suggest me , how to write all revision numbers into a file?

(or)

How to select all revision details by using command line?

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633649/svn-is-it-possible-to-get-the-list-of-revision-numbers-for-given-path

Comment: Hi @DanWilson, Here is the my code `Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/command:log /path:" + updateLocation + " /startrev:{2016-12-19} /endrev:{2016-11-11} /outfile:E:\\Sample.txt";

`

Comment: Please include your code in the question. I mistakenly edited your question to remove the winforms tag because you made no mention of it.

Comment: Please have a look on the image. I can get the particular revisions ,by default the first revision is selected. I need to select all other details also through command line.

Comment: `TortoiseProc` is really not the appropriate way to do this - it's not meant to be automated in this way. Use a Subversion library like SharpSVN to access the repository from your application rather than creating a wrapper for an external program.